# Example of non-trivial sigma-algebra that cannot have a probability measure.

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Does exist an example of non-trivial sigma-algebra that cannot have a probability measure? (Measure of a whole space is one.)

If, unlikely, no, then:
Does exist any "algorithm" of defining a probability measure on an arbitrary non-trivial sigma algebra?

(there are many similar questions on SE, but)

I tried to use famuous examples like Vitali set, but it requires additionally probability of interval to be 1 and stability under translation.

What if we don't have such requirements and can use any probability measure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$ is any set with a sigma algebra $S$ and $x \in X$ then $\mu(A)=1$ if $x \in A$ an $0$ otherwise defines a probability measure on $(X,S)$.